# Purpose of Debian "sites-available" and "sites-enabled" directories?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apache2

Can anyone tell me—in a nutshell—what the purpose of these two directories are in Debian?

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

I notice that diffing `sites-available/000-default` and `sites-enabled/default` shows they are identical.

What gives?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

sites-available contains the apache config files for each of your sites.  For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site.mysite.com
  ServerAdmin my@email.com

  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/site.mysite.com/public

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog /home/user/public_html/site.mysite.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /home/user/public_html/site.mysite.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When you want to add a new site (for example, site.mysite.com), you add it here, and use:

```
a2ensite site.mysite.com
```

To enable the site.  Once the site is enabled, a symlink to the config file is placed in the sites-enabled directory, indicating that the site is enabled.

Comment: If you want to disable a site, you would run a2dissite site.mysite.com

Comment: `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` are located in `/usr/sbin` which is currently not included in the default user path so tab completion won't work. When typing `sudo a2` and pressing the tab key however you will be offered both `a2ensite` and `a2dissite`.

Comment: I had to type in the name of my config file, such as a2ensite foo.conf and then restarted apache

Answer (score 25):

More important than the mechanics of the system is the rationale...

Debian provides the two separate directories so that if you're automatically managing your Apache configs, you can just have all of the vhosts drop into `sites-available` on all your machines, and then individual vhosts can be enabled on the server that will actually serve them.  It also means you can near-instantaneously disable a site if it's causing problems (`a2dissite example.com; /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`).

Comment: This one is **true** answer for original question.

Answer (score 7):

### Important information:

You should edit files **only** in `sites-available` directory.

**Do never** edit files inside the `sites-enabled` directory, otherwise you can have problems if your editor runs out of memory or, for any reason, it receives a SIGHUP or SIGTERM.

For example: if you are using `nano` to edit the file `sites-enabled/default` and it runs out of memory or, for any reason, it receives a SIGHUP or SIGTERM, then `nano` will create an emergency file called `default.save`, inside the `sites-enabled` directory. So, there will be an extra file inside the `sites-enabled` directory. That will prevent Apache or NGINX to start. If your site was working, it will not be anymore. You will have a hard time until you find out, in the logs, something related to the `default.save` file and, then, remove it.

In the example above, if you were editing the file inside the `sites-available` directory, nothing bad would have happened. The file `sites-available/default.save` would have been created, but it wouldn't do any harm inside the `sites-available` directory.

Comment: Very interesting! Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: Here is an example of someone who had this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808705/deployed-rails-app-still-seeing-nginx-splash-page

Comment: Something similar happened in the following link. See Melvyn comment in the answaer, about editing files in sites-enabled.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210115/webserver-with-nginx-working-until-save-file-created

Answer (score 4):

To add to those above, the file in `sites-enabled` is a symlink to the `sites-available` file:

```
ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

It’s not just the same content, it’s the same actual file!