# Is there an Nginx command to using the default conf?

Tags: nginx, configuration, defaults, stability

To use the Nginx default conf (`sites-available/default`) one needs to uncomment all relevant lines in that file.

To avoid manual uncommenting each time I install a new server environment on a new machine, what I did was to make myself a copy of the uncommented default conf, and each time I just paste it, or redirect it (`>`), to the new default conf file, in the new machine.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the above conf could change any day and if it changes tomorrow, it might **mismatch** a new Nginx I've installed with `sudo apt-get install nginx` on **some** machine.

Hence, I'm looking for a way to better cope with **my need to turn on the default Nginx conf**. I don't want to turn it on by manual uncommenting, or copy-paste a ready, uncommented version as I do now:

I aspire to turn on the default conf in a more safe way, maybe by some CLI command.

What will be a plausible way to do so?

Comment: I've no idea what your actual problem is, but I've  a vague feeling that you have some big misunderstanding how all this is supposed to work. Also, normally you install `nginx` exactly once ....

Comment: What's "all of this"? With the above code I'm able to get Nginx to work and serve apps like PHPmyadmin. Without it, no app will work. I edited my question to better explain the problem I try to cope with. I am really surprised the question was putted on hold.

Comment: In the mean time, here is my answer.  You can define the configuration file with the "-c" option.  Add DAEMON_OPTS variable to /etc/default/nginx.
But I don't think an upgrade would overwrite your configurations changes without your permission.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/424452/nginx-enable-site-command

Comment: `I aspire to turn on the default conf in  a more safe way`. Removing/adding the symlink in `sites-enabled` is the default and safe and easy way on Debian/Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

You can define the configuration file with the "-c" option.
Add the following line to `/etc/default/nginx` :

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-c  /thisismy.conf"
```

But I don't think an upgrade would overwrite your configurations changes without your permission.

Comment: I did, because that's a terrible approach, as you now ignored all the other stuff that gets included in the default config files on Debian/Ubuntu.  There is an easy, standard and supported way to enable/disable configuration blocks like vhosts - just use it.

Comment: I thought the OP wanted his own "default.conf", and that's what the "-c" option is for.

Comment: No, the `sites-available/default.conf` on Debian/Ubuntu contains just a few defaults for virtual hosts, it gets included from the main config (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`  file via an `include` statement that includes everything in `sites-enabled`. Everything in `sites-enabled` is supposed to be a symlink to a corresponding file in `sites-available` and you can activate/deactivate any block by removing or creating this symlink.

Comment: But @Sven the `default` file is still fully uncommented to be used, even if you add a symling to it from sites-enabled. My aim is to quickly uncomment the relevant conf inside it (in the end of it).