# Nginx: Running multiple web apps on same server using subdomains

Tags: nginx

I am having a `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` and I am running `nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`.

I am basically have three config files in my folder `/etc/nginx/sites-available` as I would like to route requests to:

1. myserver.com
2. immos.myserver.com
3. items.myserver.com

My `myserver.com` config file looks like the following:

```
server {
    server_name myserver.com www.myserver.com;
    root /var/www/main-application/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.myserver.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = myserver.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com www.myserver.com nlg.myserver.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

The nginx-config of my `immos.myserver.com` looks like the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name immos.myserver.com;
    root /var/www/immos-application/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

My nginx config of `items.myserver.com` looks like the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name items.myserver.com;
    root /var/www/items_application/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

All the subdomains and the domain is routed on the DNS to my server's ip.

I can open `myserver.com` and get routed to the correct page.

BUT when opening `immos.myserver.com`, `items.myserver.com` I get routed to the application that is running on `myserver.com`.

All three applications are laravel applications.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your subdomains are only configured for http. Are you trying to access them via https?

Comment: Are these files only in `sites-available` or **did you also link them in `sites-enabled` and bounce nginx?** If not, nginx isn't actually reading them. See https://serverfault.com/questions/424452/nginx-enable-site-command