# How, besides trial and error, can I know which VirtualHost Apache 2.4.10 on Debian is loaded first?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, apache-2.4

After (or rather, during a migration between web hosts because I want to keep root on my VPS) I was gently informed that my homepage was "i tried to open the site, but it opened an index site, not a normal website". I went to see what the visitor meant, and it was an autogenerated index page, in /var/www, with an "html" folder offering Debian's elaborate "It worked!" page.

I went through 000-default.conf, and made sure it specified a DocumentRoot of "/home/cjsh/mirror". Restarted. No dice. I edited a couple of other files. No dice. I globally replaced "/var/www" with "/home/cjsh/mirror". Now it displays the correct page. However, another portion is that I want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. Presently my site serves both; I'd like http://cjshayward.com to redirect to https://cjshayward.com, which 000-default.conf should do, but again it appears not to be consulted first.

I have a few dozen conf files; all but ssl-default.conf begin with \d\d\d in ascending order.

How can I either find out what files are loaded first, or tell Apache that I want the files to be loaded in e.g. lexicographic order?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the main [`httpd.conf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html) is parsed sequentially from top to bottom with one directive per line.

The files matching an [`Include`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include) directive are parsed sequentially in lexicographical order before proceeding to the next directive following that `Include` directive.
Nested `Include` directives are allowed, I.e. a file loaded resulting an `Include` directive may also use `Include` directives :)

In addition the chapter on how directives and sections are [merged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html) is useful too.

A quick listing of how virtual hosts are processed is displayed with `apachectl -S`

Debian likes each virtual host in its own file in  the `sites-available` sub directory and then using `a2enable` or `e2ensite` to set up a symlink to that include files from the `sites-enabled` directory which gets `Include`d. See [Purpose of debian "sites-available" and "sites-enabled" dirs](https://serverfault.com/questions/83508/purpose-of-debian-sites-available-and-sites-enabled-dirs)

Includes are pretty deterministic but you don't have to rely on them, simply managing a httpd.conf manually works too.